# Как парсить обычный массив с данными?

Tags: swift, swift3

У меня есть массив с очками юзеров. И мне нужно парсить этот массив, проверять есть ли в этом массиве число большее за 500 или равное 500.
Вот лично моя идея как это можно начать

```
games = try! context.fetch(Game.fetchRequest())
        for game in games {

        }
```

Как это можно сделать? P.S - данные в массив я достаю с coreData. Спасибо!

Comment: а где сам массив

Answer (score 0):

1) Вы можете используя `Predicate` сразу получить из CoreData только те результаты, которые Вам нужны:

```
var fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Score")
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "score >= 500")
        let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "score", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor]
        return request
    }
```

2) Так же Вы можете использовать `.filter` для массива:

```
let filteredArray = scores.filter({ $0 >= 500})
```